# Given the Nyquist plot, determine order and stability

Tags: homework-and-exercises

[image]

Is the nyquist plot of the open control loop. The starting point (not shown in the figure) is in the negative infinity of the imaginary axis.

What is the order of the process ?

What is the maximum gain of the controller, so that the control loop is still stable.

Comment: This question was cross-posted to Electrical Engineering SE which is IMO a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be an electronics SE or signal processing SE question. But I presume we have the plot bending back and asymptoting to the imaginary axis as $\omega\to 0$ and the plot approaches the origin as $\omega\to\infty$ right?

In which case, to get the intersection with the real axis as well as $\omega\to 0$ you have a polynomial in the denominator that is at least third order. I am assuming it will asymptote to the origin of the plane by becoming tangent to the positive imaginary axis. This means again that the system has three more poles than zeros, so it is going to be of the form:

$$H(s) \propto \frac{1}{s\,(s^2 + 2 \zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2)}$$

Assuming the plot crosses the imaginary axis at the point $0-0.5 i$  *i.e.* $\exists \omega_0 \,\ni\, H(i\,\omega_0) = 0-0.5 i$ how much do you have to scale up the above plot by, *i.e.* what is the real multiplying factor $K$ such that $H(i,\omega_0) = -1\,i$ *i.e.* the plot would be on the brink of encircling the critical point?